# CORS issue with a statically generated Nuxt 2 site and Netlify serverless function

Tags: vuejs2, cors, nuxt.js, serverless, netlify

I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue while attempting to make requests from a statically generated Nuxt.js site hosted on Netlify to a serverless function handling Mailchimp API requests. The serverless function is set up to subscribe users to a Mailchimp list.

I am able to successfully invoke the function using the `Netlify CLI` but when requesting client side (both locally and in prod) the function returns the below:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us11.api.mailchimp.com/.netlify/functions/mailchimp/mailchimp' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am setting both the headers in the serverless function and in the `netlify.toml` to allow cross-origin requests but as you can see in the error it seems I am hitting the Mailchimp API directly rather than proxying the endpoint so I am wondering if I am misunderstanding the approach to serverless functions or have missed a step in the process which is causing the error?

See code below:

**netlify.toml**

```
[dev]
  command = "yarn dev"
  targetPort = 3000

[build]
  command = "yarn generate"
  publish = "dist"
  functions = "functions/"

[[headers]]
  # Define which paths this specific [[headers]] block will cover.
  for = "/*"
    [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

**Form component**

```
...
  methods: {
    async subscribe() {
      try {
        const response = await this.$axios.$post(
          "/.netlify/functions/mailchimp/mailchimp",
          { email: this.email }
        );
        console.log(response); // You can handle success message or redirect here
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to subscribe:", error);
        // Handle error (e.g., show error message)
      }
    },
  }
```

**Serverless function**

```
// Path: /functions/mailchimp/mailchimp

const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
  server: process.env.MAILCHIMP_SERVER,
});

const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
};



exports.handler = async (event) => {
  if (event.httpMethod !== 'POST') {
    return {
      statusCode: 405,
      body: 'Method Not Allowed',
      headers: { 'Allow': 'POST' }
    }
  }

  const data = JSON.parse(event.body)

  console.log(data);

  if (!data.email) {
    return { statusCode: 422, body: 'email is required.' }
  }

  const mailchimpData = {
    email_address: data.email,
    status: "subscribed",
    skip_merge_validation: true,
  }

  try {
    await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(process.env.MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, mailchimpData)

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
      },
      body: 'Your message was sent successfully!'
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 422,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
      },
      body: `Error: ${error}`
    }
  }
}
```

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to successfully integrate the serverless functions be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The CORS error you are experiencing is due to the serverless function calling the Mailchimp API directly, bypassing the Nuxt.js proxy. To resolve this issue, it is necessary to make the Mailchimp request through the Nuxt.js proxy.

Replace the serverless function:

```
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
  server: process.env.MAILCHIMP_SERVER,
});

const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
};

const proxyMailchimpUrl = process.env.NUXT_PROXY_URL + '/mailchimp'; // Assuming Nuxt.js proxy is configured to route '/mailchimp' to the Mailchimp API

exports.handler = async (event) =>
{
  if (event.httpMethod !== 'POST') {
    return {
        statusCode: 405,
        body: 'Method Not Allowed',
        headers: { 'Allow': 'POST' }
    }
}

const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

if (!data.email) {
    return { statusCode: 422, body: 'email is required.' };
}

const mailchimpData = {
    email_address: data.email,
    status: 'subscribed',
    skip_merge_validation: true,
};

try {
    const response = await require('@nuxt/http').default.post(proxyMailchimpUrl, mailchimpData);
    console.log(response.data);

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        },
        body: 'Your message was sent successfully!'
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to subscribe:', error);
    return {
        statusCode: 422,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
        },
        body: `Error: ${error}`
    }
  }
};
```

This modified serverless function will proxy the Mailchimp request through the Nuxt.js proxy, ensuring that the CORS headers are correctly set and the request is routed to the Mailchimp API through the Nuxt.js proxy.

Comment: A serverless function isn't subject to the SOP or CORS.

Comment: The problem in the code above is that Nuxt.js makes a direct request to the Mailchimp API, bypassing the serverless function.  @jub0bs

Comment: @B_Cbk thanks for the response! Which Nuxt Proxy are your referring to? Unfortunately in my experience I cannot leverage the Axios module with proxies as I am using Nuxt static not universal (server), hence the serverless function. Or do you mean setting up some sort of middleware? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I just wanted to give you a quick answer in my busy schedule. Axios is unavailable, that's right. You should be able to make requests with `@nuxt/http` module in serverless function. If not, you can install `npm install @nuxt/http `and try using it. I'm updating the code above, if it doesn't work, I'll delete my post because a wrong solution shouldn't stay here. I gave the answers that may be within my knowledge. @strnr